# How to use ng if condition in a single div for multiple condition

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a select dropdown,and divs coming from loop.Here when I change the drop down option to city,my div id should change to one,two three which comes from details column from json.Again when I change the drop down option to state,my div id should change to title1,title2 title3  which comes from title column from json.Here it is working fine but I am creating new divs for each condition,can it possible to make in a single div with multiple condition.Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
<option value="city">Cities</option>
<option value="state">States</option>
<option value="country">Countries</option>
</select>
<div ng-if="id=='city'">
<div ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp.details}}" >hello</div>
</div>
<div ng-if="id=='state'">
<div ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp.title}}" >hello</div>
</div>
<div ng-if="id=='country'">
<div ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp.name}}" >hello</div>
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title1',
      name:'name1',
      details:'one'
    },
    {
      title: 'title2',
       name:'name2',
      details:'two'
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
       name:'name2',
      details:'three'
    }
    ]
  $scope.update = function() { 
   if($scope.x == 'city'){
   $scope.id='city';
   }
   if($scope.x == 'state'){
    $scope.id='state';
   }
   if($scope.x == 'country'){
   $scope.id='country';
   }

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, try to:

1. create an `attr` for each value - city, state and country, like so:

   ```
      if($scope.x == 'city'){  
         $scope.id='city';  
         $scope.attr = 'details';  
      }
   ```
2. Use `{{emp[attr]}}` to display values based on the dropdown selection:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title1',
      name: 'name1',
      details: 'one'
    },
    {
      title: 'title2',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'two'
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'three'
    }
  ]
  $scope.update = function() {
    if ($scope.x == 'city') {
      $scope.id = 'city';
      $scope.attr = 'details';
    }
    if ($scope.x == 'state') {
      $scope.id = 'state';
      $scope.attr = 'title';
    }
    if ($scope.x == 'country') {
      $scope.id = 'country';
      $scope.attr = 'name';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
      <option value="city">Cities</option>
      <option value="state">States</option>
      <option value="country">Countries</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}">{{emp[attr]}}</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wRQWRM

Answer (score 0):

To this in a singal element you can use a nested ternary operator. For your case it will look like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{id=='city' ? emp.details :  id=='state' ? emp.title : emp.name}}" >hello</div>
```

I didn't implement this on angular 1 but it works on angular 2. Angular built in directive (ngif, ngfor ngclass etc) works almost same for both versions.